# QBChatDialog is not work this dependency on:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

1:-this dependency is not work on QBChatDialog but QBSettings is work:

```
compile "com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:2.5.1@aar"
compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.5.1@aar") {
    transitive=true
}
```

2:-this dependency is not work on QBSettings but QBChatDialog  is working, so how can i solve this issues in android quickblox:

```
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.3.0@aar'
    compile("com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.0@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dependencies listed below :

```
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.3.3@aar'
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.3.3@aar'
compile('com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```